# HTML5 - How to get the center point of SVG text element?

Tags: html, svg, center, point

I've got problem with SVG text element. I want to find the center point of SVG text. In HTML file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <text x="300" y="300" style="font-size: 80px;" id="test">It is example text</text>
 </svg>
```

In Javascript I've got something like that:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test').childNodes[1];
var box = obj.getBBox();

var centerPoint = new Object();
centerPoint.x = box.x + box.width / 2;
centerPoint.y = box.y + box.height/ 2;
```

but it doesn't work - the center point is lower than I expected. Probably I missed something, I'm sure there is one more text attribute that I have to substract from "centerPoint.y". The "centerPoint.x" value seems to be OK. It's checked on IE9 browser, Chrome, Opera and Firefox. Results are the same.

Or maybe you've got other solution?

**Edit**

To sum up my code works properly. I rewrote whole code and it's ok now. I don't know what happend, probably my browser didn't refresh scripts at all. Setting line-height to "0" is unnecessary. getBBox it's all that I need to do that.

Anyway thank for your time and sorry for my English! :)

Comment: descenders may affect the overall positioning.  see if you can draw a rectangle around the box - that will show you more about what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Line height can be a reason. Text is normally positioned a bit higher then its center/

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` seem to get the height and width properly. Try them out and see if they work for you?

```
var centrePoint = {
    x: obj.naturalWidth / 2,
    y: obj.naturalHeight / 2
}
```

From my experience of `SVG` elements, yes they can sometimes have weird bits of padding around them like line-height, so setting `line-height:0` can help.

Also, the object returned by `getBBox()` isn't actually in pixels. It's relative to the `viewbox` of the containing `SVG` element - which is not necessarily pixels. `SVG`s on my site might have a `viewbox` of 500 by 500 but by styled to only be 25px by 25px in size. So it could be considerably different from pixels.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Results are the same if we use getBoudingClientRect or getBBox.

Check it now: http://s17.postimage.org/srm8ge2al/newone.png

Still I don't think it's center point of the text :(

Comment: I updated the answer - try `naturalHeight` etc. let me know if they work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a tighter boundingbox, then you can iterate over the characters in the text element add make your own tighter boundingbox, see the [getExtentOfChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getExtentOfChar) DOM method. However, note that this may be expensive if you have a lot of text.

Answer (score 0):

Not all glyphs are the same height. Consider the word "hay" The h is taller than the a and the y drops down below both the h and the a (the y has something called a descender). When you get the bounding box of text in SVG it gives you the glyph cell size. This generally is enough to accommodate both a ascenders i.e. h and descenders i.e. y characters. That's the way the SVG specification says to do it which is why all browsers work the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getBoundingClientRect()` in place of `getBBox()`

```
var obj = document.getElementById('test').childNodes[1];
var box = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
var centerPointX = box.left + box.width / 2;
var centerPointY = box.top + box.height/ 2;
```